# Send variable from page by Custom Button or Link Edit (visualforce page)

Tags: apex, visualforce, button, custom-link

Hello can i transfer from page by create new button (visualforce page) to other page and the other page will get the variable or i need to create it like link to the a new visualforce page with get variable ?

Comment: Can you please format your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<apex:param` tag to pass the parameters as below.

```
<apex:commandLink value="Command Link" action="{!doCommandLink}">
  <apex:param name="vfParam" value="TestValue" assignTo="{!vfParam}" />
</apex:commandLink>
```

Check this [link](https://www.xgeek.net/salesforce/the-usage-of-apexparam-in-visualforce-page/) for more details on how to use `<apex:param`.